# Create a ZIP file in Kotlin

Tags: file, kotlin, zip, compression

I'm trying to create a zip file in Kotlin.
this is the code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var files: Array<String> = arrayOf("/home/matte/theres_no_place.png", "/home/matte/vladstudio_the_moon_and_the_ocean_1920x1440_signed.jpg")
var out = ZipOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream("/home/matte/Desktop/test.zip")))
var data = ByteArray(1024)
for (file in files) {
    var fi = FileInputStream(file)
    var origin = BufferedInputStream(fi)
    var entry = ZipEntry(file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/")))
    out.putNextEntry(entry)
    origin.buffered(1024).reader().forEachLine {
        out.write(data)
    }
    origin.close()
}
out.close()}
```

the zip file is created, but the files inside are corrupt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to do it manually but I found this nice library that works perfectly:

https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip

This library is a nice wrapper of the Java Zip Utils library that include methods for zipping/unzipping both files and directories with a single function.

For zipping a single file you just need to use the `packEntry` method:

```
ZipUtil.packEntry(File("/tmp/demo.txt"), File("/tmp/demo.zip"))
```

For the case of zipping a directory and its sub-directories you can use the `pack` method:

```
val dirToCompress = Paths.get("/path/to/my/dir").toFile()
val targetOutput = Paths.get("/output/path/dir.zip").toFile()

ZipUtil.pack(dirToCompress, targetOutput)
```

The zip file should have been created in the specified target output.

You can find more details and examples in the [library's documentation](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip#examples).

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 16):

If you use Kotlin's `IOStreams.copyTo()` extension, it will do the copying work for you, and that ended up working for me.

So replace this:

```
origin.buffered(1024).reader().forEachLine {
    out.write(data)
}
```

With this:

```
origin.copyTo(out, 1024)
```

I also had issues with the `ZipEntry` having a leading slash, but that could just be because I'm on Windows.

Note: I didn't end up needing to call `closeEntry()` to get this to work but it is recommended.

Answer (score 16):

I did a mix:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val files: Array<String> = arrayOf("/home/matte/theres_no_place.png", "/home/matte/vladstudio_the_moon_and_the_ocean_1920x1440_signed.jpg")
    ZipOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream("/home/matte/Desktop/test.zip"))).use { out ->
        for (file in files) {
            FileInputStream(file).use { fi ->
                BufferedInputStream(fi).use { origin ->
                    val entry = ZipEntry(file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/")))
                    out.putNextEntry(entry)
                    origin.copyTo(out, 1024)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly!

Comment: I don't think you need to 'use' the BufferedInputStream. It will get closed when it's parent stream - FileInputStream gets closed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution working with subfolders:

```
fun addFolderToZip(
    folder: String,
    destination: String,
    zipFileName: String = folder.substring(folder.lastIndexOf("/"))
) {

    val folderToZip = File(folder)
    var out: ZipOutputStream? = null
    try {
        out = ZipOutputStream(
            BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream("$destination/$zipFileName"))
        )
        recursivelyAddZipEntries(folderToZip, folderToZip.absolutePath, out)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("ZIP Err", e.message)
    } finally {
        out?.close()
    }

}


private fun recursivelyAddZipEntries(
    folder: File,
    basePath: String,
    out: ZipOutputStream
) {

    val files = folder.listFiles() ?: return
    for (file in files) {

        if (file.isDirectory) {
            recursivelyAddZipEntries(file, basePath, out)
        } else {
            val origin = BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(file))
            origin.use {
                val entryName = file.path.substring(basePath.length)
                out.putNextEntry(ZipEntry(entryName))
                origin.copyTo(out, 1024)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You are writing an empty byte array to the `out` for each line of an input file.

2) There is no need in `BufferedReader` because it is enough to read and write bytes instead of lines (which would lead the unpacked content not to be matched with the original).

3) All streams should be closed in the case of exceptions. Use method `use` like try-with-resources in java.

4) `val` instead `var` there possible

5) Don't use absolute paths except for the quick test snippets.

6) This snippet is not in idiomatic way for Kotlin (see the Todd's answer)

So this is how it should work (though in the Java way):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val files: Array<String> = arrayOf("/home/matte/theres_no_place.png", "/home/matte/vladstudio_the_moon_and_the_ocean_1920x1440_signed.jpg")
    ZipOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream("/home/matte/Desktop/test.zip"))).use { out ->
        val data = ByteArray(1024)
        for (file in files) {
            FileInputStream(file).use { fi ->
                BufferedInputStream(fi).use { origin ->
                    val entry = ZipEntry(file)
                    out.putNextEntry(entry)
                    while (true) {
                        val readBytes = origin.read(data)
                        if (readBytes == -1) {
                            break
                        }
                        out.write(data, 0, readBytes)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I've ran this snippet with my files and it worked OK.

Answer (score 2):

The code can be cleaned up a bit to separate concerns and take  advantage of [use](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html):

```kotlin
fun File.bufferedOutputStream(size: Int = 8192) = BufferedOutputStream(this.outputStream(), size)
fun File.zipOutputStream(size: Int = 8192) = ZipOutputStream(this.bufferedOutputStream(size))
fun File.bufferedInputStream(size: Int = 8192) = BufferedInputStream(this.inputStream(), size)
fun File.asZipEntry() = ZipEntry(this.name)

fun archive(files: List<File>, destination: File) =
    destination.zipOutputStream().use { zipOs ->
        files.forEach { file ->
            zipOs.putNextEntry(file.asZipEntry())
            file.bufferedInputStream().use { bIs -> bIs.copyTo(zipOs) }
        }
    }


fun main() {
    val files = listOf(
        File("/Users/xor/Downloads/Ghibli/kaguyahime006.jpg"),
        File("/Users/xor/Downloads/Ghibli/kaguyahime035.jpg")
    )

    val destination = File("/Users/xor/work/kotlin/scratchpad-kotlin-java/src/main/kotlin/main/archive.zip")

    archive(files, destination)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate / explain the variable / object ```it``` which is used to perform operation ```it.putNextEntry(file.asZipEntry())``` ? Where & How it is defined ?

Comment: it is the zip output stream exposed by `use`. Similar to `bIs -> bIs.copyTo(zipOs)` , I amended the example for clarity

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler solution, also provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/63828765/3792198

```
fun test() {

        val fullPath: String = tempFolder.absolutePath // Folder to be zipped
        val zipFilePath = File(baseDirectory, "newTest.zip")// new zip file

        zipAll(fullPath, zipFilePath.absolutePath)

}




private fun zipAll(directory: String, zipFile: String) {
    val sourceFile = File(directory)

    println("directory: $directory")
    println("zipFile: $zipFile")

    val inputDirectory = sourceFile
    val outputZipFile = File(zipFile)

    ZipOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(outputZipFile))).use { zos ->
        inputDirectory.walkTopDown().forEach { file ->
            val zipFileName = file.absolutePath.removePrefix(inputDirectory.absolutePath).removePrefix("/")
            val entry = ZipEntry( "$zipFileName${(if (file.isDirectory) "/" else "" )}")
            zos.putNextEntry(entry)
            if (file.isFile) {
                file.inputStream().copyTo(zos)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and it is not adding anything to the zip file, i even debugged the part where if(file.isfile()) is being used and the code is antering the conditional, yet the zip is always ampty. was this working with any folder really?

Answer (score 0):

Combined two previously proposed options into a more universal solution that allows you to set arbitrary names in the archive for source files

```
private const val DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE: Int = 8 * 1024
fun File.bufferedOutputStream(size: Int = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) = BufferedOutputStream(this.outputStream(), size)
fun File.zipOutputStream(size: Int = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) = ZipOutputStream(this.bufferedOutputStream(size))
fun File.bufferedInputStream(size: Int = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) = BufferedInputStream(this.inputStream(), size)

fun archive(files: Map<String, File>, destination: File) {
    destination.zipOutputStream().use { zipStream ->
        files.forEach { entry ->
            val file = entry.value
            val name = if (file.isDirectory) "${entry.key}/" else entry.key
            zipStream.putNextEntry(ZipEntry(name))
            if (file.isFile) {
                file.bufferedInputStream().use { bis -> bis.copyTo(zipStream) }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun use(){
    val zip = mutableMapOf<String, File>()
    zip.put("internal/3.jpg", File("/home/qixi/3.jpg"))
    zip.put("4.jpg", File("/home/qixi/4.jpg"))
    archive(zip, File("/home/qixi/file.zip"))
}
```