# Zip byte[] in Kotlin. Java code to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to use this Java code but converting it to Kotlin in Android Studio, but I don't find a equivalent in kotlin for `setSize(..)` and `.length` in Kotlin. Could anyone help me?

```
public static byte[] zipBytes(String filename, byte[] input) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
    entry.setSize(input.length);
    zos.putNextEntry(entry);
    zos.write(input);
    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46222055/12511801) and its answers might help you. If not, please share if you did search in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Array in Kotlin has `size` field instead of Java array `length` and `size` field is `Int` in Kotlin, but `ZipEntry.setSize(long size)` accepts only `long`. So you can do something like this:

```
entry.setSize(input.size.toLong())
```

Or in more Kotlin idiomatic way:

```
entry.size = input.size.toLong()
```

Answer (score 1):

when you write a byteArray in kotlin like this :

```
 val byteArray = ByteArray(1024)
 var length = byteArray.size
```

documentation says

> An array of bytes. When targeting the JVM, instances of this class are represented as `byte[]`.
>     @constructor Creates a new array of the specified [size], with all elements initialized to zero.

to prove it, checking the byte code created is this:

```
 byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
 int test = byteArray.length;
```

therefor in your case a can code like this.

```
entry.size = byteArray.size
```

but type of `size` is `int` and `entry.size` needs a `long` value, just add `.toLong()` to `size` for fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

Import:

```
import java.io.IOException
import java.text.DecimalFormat
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream
```

And you code in kotlin:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun zipBytes(filename: String?, input: ByteArray): ByteArray? {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val zos = ZipOutputStream(baos)
    val entry = ZipEntry(filename)
    entry.size = input.size.toLong()
    zos.putNextEntry(entry)
    zos.write(input)
    zos.closeEntry()
    zos.close()
    return baos.toByteArray()
}
```